# Qt download progress not being triggered after sequential aborts

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming

For an old tool using Qt 5.3.2 we recently encountered a problem. Using `QNetwork` manager we are downloading files but before we download them we do a check whether they can be downloaded from a certain region. To do this we do an abort at the very first progress indication.

Since recently we do not get a `downloadProgress` signal any more after some aborts and it only happens with a very fast network connection. Over WiFi it doesn't reproduce. What could be the problem?

Some code snippets:

StartDownload:

```
networkManager->get(request);
networkReply->setReadBufferSize(4 * 1024 * 1024);
    connect(networkReply, SIGNAL(finished()),
        this, SLOT(onDownloadFinished()));

connect(networkReply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)),
        this, SLOT(onDownloadProgress()));

connect(networkReply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
        this, SLOT(onDownloadError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));

connect(networkReply, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),
        this, SLOT(onDownloadSslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));

connect(networkReply, SIGNAL(encrypted()),
        this, SLOT(onEncrypted()));
```

OnDownloadProgress:

```
void DownloadManager::onDownloadProgress()
{
    networkReply->abort();
                nrAborts++;
                startDownload(myurl);
}
```

OnDownloadFinished:

```
void DownloadManager::onDownloadFinished()
{
    networkReply->deleteLater();
}
```

Comment: "it only happens with a very fast network connection" - may be download finishes before it have to send any progress? did you check if finished() is received?

Comment: We investigated that but the files are quite big so this is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the read buffer was full before the first `onDownloadProgress` and was never read all got stuck. Subscribing to `readyRead` and reading the data with `networkReply->readAll()` causes the buffer to be flushed and the `downloadProgress` signals to be called.